# MS-Word VBA Fit method for canvas

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word, when right-clicking over a canvas frame, there is a [fit option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1dDK.png). How to execute this programmatically in VBA? I can't find the method in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to have been left out of the object model, like the rest of the Canvas-specific right-click commands. You may be able to work around it with this, it assumes that Shapes(1) is the drawing canvas:

```
With ActiveDocument.Shapes(1)
  CommandBars.ExecuteMso "DrawingCanvasFit"
End With
```